# How do I output line breaks from xsl:value of

Tags: xslt

I have this statement

```
xsl:value-of select="metadata/line1"/
```

where line1 is in the souce xml is:

```
Microsoft Windows 7 is installed&lt;br/&gt
```

The HTML output turns out to be:

```
Microsoft Windows 7 is installed&lt;br/&gt;
```

I want it to actually insert the break after the word installed instead of outputting the literal `&lt;br/&gt`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that what you like to do is "unescape" some xml content. If I'm right disable-output-escaping should help. Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="metadata/line1" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

E.g.: [How to unescape XML characters with help of XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463155/how-to-unescape-xml-characters-with-help-of-xslt)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **xsl:select**, use **xsl:copy-of**

It will render the HTML as well

See http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_copy-of.asp

You can even try **`<xsl:value-of select="  " disable-output-escaping="yes" />`**